# Drawing a horizontal and vertical line in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[image]

I have an image that contains a table. There is a horizontal dotted line in the table which I want to replace with a solid horizontal line. Also, I have to draw the vertical lines between the columns. Can anyone help me, what should be my approach? I am using python.

Comment: please add a reproducible example that generates the output your're showing!

Comment: The image I have shown is the input image.

Comment: the input to what? are you trying to read in the table from the image??

Comment: @raphael: the OP wants to draw horizontal and vertical separators.

Comment: Is this a school exercise or a real life problem ?

Comment: Its a real life problem

Comment: @raphael yes! I am trying to read the table from the image

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Performing an horizontal erosion is a good start to find the positions of the horizontal lines, and delimit sections of the document. Then a large vertical erosion will help you find the columns, though this is more challenging.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the code to get the above results.

Comment: @mohdehshankhan: no, was done with proprietary software. But that would be three lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this output is good for you or not but as @Yves Daoust said, erosion processes may benefit your problem.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObtgS.jpg)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = cv2.imread('hough.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel = np.ones((3,12), np.uint8)  #for horizontal erosion
e_im = cv2.erode(gray, kernel, iterations=1)  #performing erosion



edges = cv2.Canny(e_im,190,245,apertureSize = 3)     #edges
minLineLength=333
#houghlines for detecting those erosion lines
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=0.5,theta=np.pi/180, threshold=222,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=7) 

a,b,c = lines.shape
# Draw the lines
if lines is not None:
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        l = lines[i][0]
        cv2.line(gray, (l[0], l[1]), (l[2], l[3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imwrite("e_im.jpg",gray)
```